# Search a Custom DataClass for Results

Tags: .net

I have built a custom Data Class that stores IP Address Details.

```
        Public Class IPAddressDataItem

        Private _ID As Integer
        Private _IP As String
        Private _Name As String

        Public Property ID() As Integer
            Get
                Return _ID
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _ID = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property IP() As String
            Get
                Return _IP
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _IP = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property Name() As String
            Get
                Return _Name
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _Name = value
            End Set
        End Property\

        Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal ip As String, ByVal name As String)
            _ID = id
            _IP = ip
            _Name = name
        End Sub

    End Class
```

What I'm trying to figure out how to do is search it for specific data.

Example.. I send it an IP address and it will return the name to me.

Does anyone know how I would do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to put the object in a collection.  To do this, you need to choose a data structure (i.e. List, ArrayList, etc)

```
Dim Items as List(Of IPAddressDataItem)
```

Then, you can iterate through the collection, find the item based on the search criteria and return the data required.

```
Function GetName(ByVal IP As String) As String
    For Each Item As IPAddressDataItem In Items
        If Item.IP.CompareTo(IP) = 0 Then
             Return Item.Name
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Right now, if you have an instance of the object, you can just access the property directly.

Comment: Yup, I'm putting the object into a collection.  I will try your iteration.. .thanks.